# ES File Explorer Pro returning "server not found" when accessing a SMB share on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, es-file-explorer, cifs

With a Windows machine, I can connect with IP, user, and password to some Linux shares. With ES File Explorer Pro, I get strange "server not found" messages.

This is what I do:

1. Open ES File Explorer Pro
2. Search the LAN (the machine is listed)
3. Access the machine (I notice it's getting all the shares listed)
4. Entering a folder gives a permission error. So I add the folder to ES File Explorer server bookmarks and try to access it again, but I get a "server not found" error.
5. Then I edit the bookmark (and notice it's logging as an anonymous user) so I set the domain with the machine name, server adding `smb://ip/share/` to the address, user, and password. And still, I get "server not found".

All the other machines, some Linux and some Windows are accessing Just fine. Except for the Android devices with ES File Explorer Pro.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following on the Linux machine:

1. Open Terminal and type `cd /etc/samba/`
2. `sudo gedit smb.conf` (Just edit it with superuser privileges on you favorite text editor). Delete all the text you see here, make the file empty.
3. Now type in the file:

   ```
   [Name you want to get shown of the folder]
   path = path of folder you want to share
   browseable = yes
   read only = no
   ```
4. Save it and exit. Now open Terminal and type `smbpasswd -a 'username'`. Note that this username must be the name of the user present on your Linux machine. Then type and confirm the password. This password can be anything.
5. Then type the following commands

   ```
   service smbd start
   service nmbd start
   ```

That's it for Linux machine. Now you can browse it from ES File Explorer. Just go to LAN and search. Remember to keep your Android device and Linux machine on the same network before proceeding. If your machine shows up, type the username and password you entered for **Samba** server and **not** Linux username and password. It should connect as I use this process myself and it works 100%.